# Spring MVC - MockHttpServletResponse Adds charset to Content-Type - How to disable that?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test, spring-mvc-test

When testing my endpoint with MockMvc, the tests are failing because my endpoint returns content type `application/json`, but `MockHttpServletResponse` is adding the charset option, then the test fails saying that `application/json;charset=UTF-8` was found while expecting `application/json`.

Is this a bug, or is there a way to prevent that from happening?

My expectation is that `MockHttpServletResponse` should not be adding `;charset=UTF-8`.